# Equivalent of Request.serializeResponseJSON - Migration Alamofire 5

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have a problem with the following code:

```
func request(url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (AFDataResponse<Any>) -> Void) {
    let httpResponse = fakeResponse.response
    let data = fakeResponse.data
    let error = fakeResponse.error
    let result = Request.serializeResponseJSON(options: .allowFragments, response: httpResponse, data: data, error: error)

    guard let url = urlBuild(queryType: "q", from: "0", to: "10", uri: nil) else { return }
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

    completionHandler(AFDataResponse(request: urlRequest, response: httpResponse, data: data, result: result))
}
```

I get the following error with Alamofire 5: Type 'Request' has no member 'serializeResponseJSON'.

I'm new to development with Swift and Alamofire, and I can't find a method equivalent to Request.serializeResponseJSON in Alamofire 5.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: u got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

All of the `serialize` methods from previous versions of Alamofire have been refactored into concrete types. For example, `serializeResponseJSON` has been replaced by the `JSONResponseSerializer`, which you can use with the `response(responseSerializer:)` method. However, for your usage, you shouldn't need to create an instance directly, as you can pass the same parameters to `responseJSON`. I suggest you use `responseDecodable` with `Decodable` types instead of `responseJSON`, as it will ensure your types are properly parsed.

I also suggest you read through our [Usage](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md), [Advanced Usage](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md), and [API](https://alamofire.github.io/Alamofire) documentation and find some newer tutorials as you start using Alamofire.